# Dagger 2 trouble @Inject-ing FirebaseMessagingService

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-messaging, dagger-2

I recently tried to migrate the application I'm working on from `GCM` to `FCM`.  While doing so, I found that where I'd previously been using `Dagger 2 (2.0.2)` to provide instances of my `Retrofit` APIs and other user-data managers inside the service (with no problems), I could no longer do so for the `FirebaseMessagingService`.

Whenever I'd try to compile with a subclass of `FirebaseMessagingService` listed in my `Dagger 2 Component` interface, I'd get an `IllegalArgumentException`. After digging through some code, it seems that the exception is thrown when `Dagger 2` tries to validate a class name and finds that the first letter isn't uppercase. `FirebaseMessagingService`, at least on my end, inherits from a uglified / minified codebase, and its immediate superclass is `zzb` (`public class FirebaseMessagingService extends com.google.firebase.iid.zzb`).

My best guess is that this is the culprit. If this really is the problem, I'm not sure what to do about this aside from stick to `GCM` for now. Anyone have any ideas or similar experience with this?

**EDIT: I got the chance to ask one of the Firebase developers about this issue: https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/4upj1o/beware_of_the_new_firebase/d5tdbk3 - No resolution.  I'm probably just going to avoid direct injection and consolidate to a static API provider.**

Comment: could you add your dependencies to the question?

Comment: I @Inject into a FirebaseMessaging subclass with Dagger 2 and have no problems. Can you post the relevant code of your Component and FirebaseMessagingService subclass so we can help you better?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After half day of struggle, finally moving to Dagger 2.7 fixed the issue.

```
compile "com.google.dagger:dagger:2.7"
apt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.7"
```

Comment: I confirm this worked for me. No breaking changes after updating from 2.0 to 2.7.

Answer (score 0):

We had the same issue, Dagger does some silly validation for class uppercase classname and encounters an obfuscated classname, which actually looks like

```
public class FirebaseService extends xxab {   

}
```

*(**xxab** is just random name that proguard spits in obfuscation pass and I can remember the exact)*

We did silly workaround, not elegant, but worked:

```
public class FirebaseServiceProvider { //not real provider, though
   public FirebaseServiceProvider(...params){
      mInstance = ...
   }
  public FirebaseService getService(){
   return mInstance;
  }
}
```

In the `@Module`:

```
@Singleton
@Provides
public FirebaseServiceProvider providesFirebaseServiceProvider(){    
 return new FirebaseServiceProvider(.....);
}
```

Injection:

```
@Inject
FirebaseServiceProvider mFirebaseServiceProvider;
```

Usage:

```
mFirebaseServiceProvider.getService().doStuff();
```